# Tkinter Buttons Not Right Size / X Error: Bad Alloc

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing a Tkinter script, but I have reached an error. When I run my script, all my buttons are quite small and don't act correctly. For example, one of my buttons is supposed to open a file dialogue, but instead, it returns the error code:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadAlloc (insufficient resources for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  53 (X_CreatePixmap)
  Serial number of failed request:  4750
  Current serial number in output stream:  4769
```

However, when I ran my code on a Windows machine instead of my Linux (Ubuntu) machine, it worked fine.
Here is my code:

```
import qrtools
from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog import *
class Decode:
   def __init__(self,master):
       self.l = StringVar()
       self.master = master
       self.frame = Frame(self.master)
       self.browse = Button(master,text="Choose a File:", command = self.filenameget).pack()
       self.label = Label(master)
       self.label.pack()
       self.dcode = Button(master,text = "You Haven't Chosen A File Yet!")
       self.dcode.pack()
       self.dcodedata = Label(master)
       self.dcodedata.pack()
       self.quitbutt = Button(master, text = 'Back To Main Page',command = self.q).pack()
   def q(self):
       import subprocess
       subprocess.check_call(['python2.7','start.py'])
       quit()
   def filenameget(self):
       t = askopenfilename()
       print t
       self.label.config(text = t)
       self.dcode.config(text = 'Decode', command = self.get_decode)
   def get_decode(self):
       qr = qrtools.QR()
       qr.decode(str(self.label.cget("text")))
       self.dcodedata.config(text=str(qr.data))
def main():
   root = Tk()
   dc = Decode(root)
   root.title = "Qr Decoder By: Brian Ton"
   root.mainloop()
if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

In addition, I tried to run a much simpler program, but to still no avail.

Here is the code to the simple program:

```
from Tkinter import *
master = Tk()
def print_test():
   print 'Hello'
button = Button(master, text = "Test Button", command = print_test)
button.pack()
mainloop()
```

My main questions are:

- Is this an Ubuntu Issue?
- If so, is there a workaround?

If you want to look at some screenshots, they are also attached.

[Ubuntu Qr Decoder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTlj2.png) 
[Windows Qr Decoder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40SGu.png) 
[Simple Program on Ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTDe7.png) 
[Simple Program on Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbusb.png)

Comment: I can't replicate this on Windows 10 with Python 3.6.2. Sounds to me like it's an OS/install issue, have you tried a fresh install of Python and tkinter on your linux box?

Comment: I reinstalled linux, and it worked! However, if this error comes up again, what should I do?

Comment: No clue, I suggested reinstalling because it sounded like it was a problem with the install rather than with Python/tkinter.